# fast way to get an element from a string in java

Tags: java, substring

I am trying to get an element from my string wich I have attained thtough a `getSelectedValue().toString` from a JList.
It returns `[1] testString`

What I am trying to do it only get the 1 from the string. Is there a way to only get that element from the string or remove all else from the string?

I have tried:

```
String longstring = Customer_list.getSelectedValue().toString();
int index = shortstring.indexOf(']');
String firstPart = myStr.substring(0, index);
```

Comment: yes there is. Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: @KevinEsche  
I have tried  
String longstring;  
longstring = Customer_list.getSelectedValue().toString();  
int index = shortstring.indexOf(']');  
String firstPart = myStr.substring(0, index);

Comment: you allmost had it, `String#substring(int)` defines the substring from the beginning index to the end. This will just give you everything after the `[1]`. if you use `String#substring(int,int)`, which is defined as create a substring from pos `x` to excluse pos `y` then you could do it like this:  `longstring.substring(0, longstring.indexOf("]") + 1)`.

Comment: This indeed did remove the second part of the string. Thank you! All i need to figure out is how to remove the "[" and "]". Would I do that through the same way?

Comment: you could make use of the `String#replace(charSequence, charSequence)` method. The first parameter should be either `"["` or `"]"`, your second could be a empty String as `""`. Just call it twice after each other and the brackets should be gone.

Comment: @KevinEsche    that worked for me!  
inline `String longstring = Customer_list.getSelectedValue().toString();  
            String shortstring = longstring.substring(0, longstring.indexOf("]") + 1);  
            String shota = shortstring.replace("[", "");  
            String shortb = shota.replace("]", "");`,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many ways to do it, for example

1. Regex
2. `String#replaceAll`
3. `String#substring`

See below code to use all methods.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;  
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class Test {  
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    String[] data = { "[1] test", " [2] [3] text ", " just some text " };

    for (String s : data) {
        String r0 = null;
        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\[(.*?)\\]").matcher(s);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            r0 = matcher.group(1);
        }
        System.out.print(r0 + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();

    for (String s : data) {
        String r1 = null;
        r1 = s.replaceAll(".*\\[|\\].*", "");
        System.out.print(r1 + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();

    for (String s : data) {
        String r2 = null;
        int i = s.indexOf("[");
        int j = s.indexOf("]");
        if (i != -1 && j != -1) {
            r2 = s.substring(i + 1, j);
        }
        System.out.print(r2 + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    }
}
```

However results may vary, for example `String#replaceAll` will give you wrong results when input is not what you expecting.

> `1 2 null`
>
> `1 3  just some text`
>
> `1 2 null`

Answer (score 0):

What worked best for me is the `String#replace(charSequence, charSequence)` combined with `String#substring(int,int)`

I have done as followed:

```
        String longstring = Customer_list.getSelectedValue().toString();
        String shortstring = longstring.substring(0, longstring.indexOf("]") + 1);
        String shota = shortstring.replace("[", "");
        String shortb = shota.replace("]", "");
```

My string has been shortened, and the [ and ] have been removed thereafter in 2 steps.