# Is there any method to remove plain braces

Tags: regex, vim, vi, greedy

is there any way to remove blank braces with regular expression or any other method?

eg:

```
i/p text :- It is \text{only} {an} \textbf{example} to {show} my {requirement}.

o/p :- It is \text{only} an \textbf{example} to show my requirement.
```

Comment: Yes there is.  Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Try looking at my question, it has a good answer in it.
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33099819/fast-way-to-get-an-element-from-a-string-in-java)

Comment: I think you can use `\(^\|\s\+\){\(\w\+\)}` and replace with `\1\2`.

Comment: i didn't get any idea so far, is there any reserved command in "vim" to replace?. if i try "%s/\s{\([^}]*\)}/\1/g" then if a text comes like "It is \text{only} {an} \textbf{example} to {sh{o}w} my {requirement}, then it should be wrong.

Comment: In Vim, capturing group is defined with `\(...\)`, not with `()`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it depends on the magic setting. or `\v \V \m \M prefix`

Comment: @Kent: I know, I just assume the settings are default.

Comment: oh! i forgot to put slash,

Comment: Does it work with my expression?

Comment: no, if a text comes like: input:-  It is \text{only} {an} \textbf{example} to {sh{o}w} my {requirement}. required output:- it is \text{only} an \textbf{example} to show my requirement.

Comment: I cannot help with that, but perhaps, you will find [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084210/remove-a-pair-of-parentheses-brackets-or-braces-in-vim) helpful.

Comment: ok, thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
:%s/\(\^\|\s\+\){\([^}]*\)}/\1\2/g
```

- `\(\^\|\s\+\)`: Matches to the whitespace before `{…}` (becomes `\1`)
- `{`: Literal left curly brace
- `\([^}]*\)`: Matches to the word inside `{…}` (becomes `\2`)
- `}`: Literal right curly brace

So `\1\2` will be the whitespace (`\1`) before `{…}`, and then the word (`\2`) without `{`, `}`.